# How to find all files on computer with creation/modification time later than specific date?

Tags: python, file, datetime, python-3.6

Using Python 3.6, I'd like to find all files (with all possible extensions) on my computer (with OS Windows) which were created or modified after 5 December 2018. Could you please tell me, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You should look up the parents drive and check for modification time on all files. See this pointer at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python

Comment: Umar Yusuf, thank you!

Comment: If you were helped by my answer, you can accept it by clicking on the green checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution I found (works in Python 3.3 and above, because it uses `pathlib`). This changes your current directory to the root directory and does the calculations on all descendent files recursively:

```
import time, os, os.path

def get_new_paths():
    os.chdir("/")
    for path in pathlib.Path("/").glob("**/*"):  # Do a recursive search across all files
        if os.path.getmtime(path) > 1543986000:
            yield path
```

`1543986000` is the exact timestamp of December 5th, 2018, 00:00:00 GMT. Just be mindful that your computer probably has millions of files and this will definitely eat up a lot of RAM.

Comment: Thank you very much!
How did you convert 5 December 2018 to 1543986000? Using the following code:

import time, datetime;
date1 = "05/12/2018";
time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(date1, "%d/%m/%Y").timetuple())

I obtained 1543968000.0

Comment: @Leonid I just guesstimated until I found the correct value. I hope I didn't copy an incorrect value.